# Can I map types where the source has fewer fields than the destination?

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

Say I have a Business Object like this:

```
public class CustomerBusiness
{
  Guid ID;
  decimal Salary;
  datetime DateOfBirth;
}
```

and a data object like this:

```
public class CustomerData
    {
      Guid ID;
      decimal Salary;
      datetime DateOfBirth;
      string Name;
    }
```

Say I know the Name and Address when I map the Business Object to the Data Object.

```
CustomerBusiness customerBusiness = new CustomerBusiness();
customerBusiness.Id = Guid.NewID();
customerBusiness.Salary = 30000M;
customerBusiness.DateOfBirth = new DateTime(1960,01,01);

string name = "Bert";
```

I believe I have two options:

1) Change the CustomerBusiness object to include the `name` and `address` members.

2) Do this in the application:

```
CustomerData = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<CustomerData>(customerBusiness);
CustomerData.Name = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<string>(name);
```

3) Do this:

```
string name = "Bert";
CustomerData = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<CustomerData>(customerBusiness);
CustomerData.Name = name;
```

Which option is more appropriate? Is there another option I have not considered?

I realise this may sound a bit pedantic as all options work, however I am trying to follow the principle of least astonishment.

Comment: You're mixing things that are logically separate abstractions.  Tease them apart, and (use composition to) relate them to each other as needed.  The conflated items you have are something like: a business, an addresses, a person, a customer, employment of person at business.

Comment: @Erik Eidt, the customer has a salary in this case (it is not an employee).  I have removed all references to Address to keep it simple.

Comment: If the customer business object doesn't already contain this data, the least astonishing thing is to do your automapping and assign the name and address afterwards, unless you plan on adding (and populating) name and address fields to the customer business object for other legitimate design reasons.

Comment: @Robert Harvey, is it a "legitimate design reason" to duplicate all the properties in the Data Model in the Domain Model just to make mapping between the two simpler? I guess not? Say I have a property: Surname that is only used by CustomerData for CRUD operations, then I guess it should not appear as a property of CustomerDomain?

Comment: Data Transfer Objects are a perfectly valid technique.  So are Adapters and Facades.  The real question is, *will they benefit you?*  Or, more specifically, *are the benefits worth the costs?*

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can map types where the [domain] source has fewer fields than the [DAL] destination by simply only mapping the domain fields and ignoring the rest of the DAL fields. Depending on your ORM, doing this will require you to either repopulate the target DAL enity prior to mapping so the other fields are not 'lost' or writing such that only the domain mapped fields are persisted across to the database via some sort of 'update desttable set field1=@data1 where id=@id' statement.

Note: This is a purely DAL implementation detail, but it is concerning that your Domain objects are being New()ed up and its properties assigned directly. If this isn't example code then you may not be working within the DDD philosophy.

Ill Ignore the auto mapping tool for the moment because it may be confusing the issue.

Assumption 1: A [customerbusiness] can only exist if a [customer] also exists (and has been persisted).

Assumption 2: [customerbusiness] is a separate Aggregate Root to [customer]

Assumption 3: you are using some ORM to represent your DB and generate the data object structures

So in this instance it seems straightforward, your DAL implementation of  CustomerBusinessRepository makes sure that only the relevant data elements in the db are modified during a save eg:

```
public class CustomerBusinessRepository  : ICustomerBusinessRepository 
{

  public Save(Domain.CustomerBusiness domainEntity) {
     DAL.CustomerData dalEntity = _DB.FetchById<CustomerData>(domainEntity.Id);
     MapToDal(domainEntity, dalEntity);
     _DB.Update(dalEntity);
  }

  /*This just for example, use your own Mapper */
  private void MapToDal(Domain.CustomerBusiness domainEntity, DAL.CustomerData dalEntity) {
     dalEntity.Salary = domainEntity.Salary;
     dalEntity.DateOfBirth = domainEntity.DateOfBirth
  }
}
```